# Multivariate linear hypothesis testing using statsmodels in Python

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, multivariate-testing

I am trying to run a multivariate regression model using statsmodels, but there appears to be no implementation of that yet, so in the meantime, what I did was to run a manova model on the data like below:

```
# the modules
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.multivariate.manova import MANOVA
from statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols import _MultivariateOLS
from statsmodels.multivariate.multivariate_ols import MultivariateTestResults

# manova
mod = MANOVA.from_formula('se + em ~ pv + ed + fs + hp', df)
mod_mvtest = mod.mv_test()
mod_mvtest.summary_frame

# the output
pd.DataFrame({'Value': {('Intercept', "Wilks' lambda"): 0.35959042974944566,
  ('Intercept', "Pillai's trace"): 0.6404095702505543,
  ('Intercept', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 1.780941641569207,
  ('Intercept', "Roy's greatest root"): 1.780941641569207,
  ('pv', "Wilks' lambda"): 0.9995874157798398,
  ('pv', "Pillai's trace"): 0.00041258422016027143,
  ('pv', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 0.0004127545161604391,
  ('pv', "Roy's greatest root"): 0.0004127545161604391,
  ('ed', "Wilks' lambda"): 0.9947762433747658,
  ('ed', "Pillai's trace"): 0.005223756625234229,
  ('ed', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 0.005251187550994082,
  ('ed', "Roy's greatest root"): 0.005251187550994082,
  ('fs', "Wilks' lambda"): 0.9906903180436285,
  ('fs', "Pillai's trace"): 0.009309681956371496,
  ('fs', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 0.009397166588602426,
  ('fs', "Roy's greatest root"): 0.009397166588602426,
  ('hp', "Wilks' lambda"): 0.9643721311041931,
  ('hp', "Pillai's trace"): 0.035627868895806984,
  ('hp', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 0.036944108759150426,
  ('hp', "Roy's greatest root"): 0.036944108759150426},
 'Num DF': {('Intercept', "Wilks' lambda"): 2,
  ('Intercept', "Pillai's trace"): 2.0,
  ('Intercept', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 2,
  ('Intercept', "Roy's greatest root"): 2,
  ('pv', "Wilks' lambda"): 2,
  ('pv', "Pillai's trace"): 2.0,
  ('pv', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 2,
  ('pv', "Roy's greatest root"): 2,
  ('ed', "Wilks' lambda"): 2,
  ('ed', "Pillai's trace"): 2.0,
  ('ed', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 2,
  ('ed', "Roy's greatest root"): 2,
  ('fs', "Wilks' lambda"): 2,
  ('fs', "Pillai's trace"): 2.0,
  ('fs', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 2,
  ('fs', "Roy's greatest root"): 2,
  ('hp', "Wilks' lambda"): 2,
  ('hp', "Pillai's trace"): 2.0,
  ('hp', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 2,
  ('hp', "Roy's greatest root"): 2},
 'Den DF': {('Intercept', "Wilks' lambda"): 11608.0,
  ('Intercept', "Pillai's trace"): 11608.0,
  ('Intercept', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 11608.000000002476,
  ('Intercept', "Roy's greatest root"): 11608,
  ('pv', "Wilks' lambda"): 11608.0,
  ('pv', "Pillai's trace"): 11608.0,
  ('pv', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 11608.000000002476,
  ('pv', "Roy's greatest root"): 11608,
  ('ed', "Wilks' lambda"): 11608.0,
  ('ed', "Pillai's trace"): 11608.0,
  ('ed', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 11608.000000002476,
  ('ed', "Roy's greatest root"): 11608,
  ('fs', "Wilks' lambda"): 11608.0,
  ('fs', "Pillai's trace"): 11608.0,
  ('fs', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 11608.000000002476,
  ('fs', "Roy's greatest root"): 11608,
  ('hp', "Wilks' lambda"): 11608.0,
  ('hp', "Pillai's trace"): 11608.0,
  ('hp', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 11608.000000002476,
  ('hp', "Roy's greatest root"): 11608},
 'F Value': {('Intercept', "Wilks' lambda"): 10336.585287667678,
  ('Intercept', "Pillai's trace"): 10336.585287667676,
  ('Intercept', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 10336.585287667674,
  ('Intercept', "Roy's greatest root"): 10336.585287667678,
  ('pv', "Wilks' lambda"): 2.3956272117948725,
  ('pv', "Pillai's trace"): 2.3956272117951882,
  ('pv', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 2.3956272117951882,
  ('pv', "Roy's greatest root"): 2.3956272117951882,
  ('ed', "Wilks' lambda"): 30.477892545969606,
  ('ed', "Pillai's trace"): 30.477892545969652,
  ('ed', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 30.477892545969645,
  ('ed', "Roy's greatest root"): 30.477892545969652,
  ('fs', "Wilks' lambda"): 54.54115488024848,
  ('fs', "Pillai's trace"): 54.54115488024848,
  ('fs', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 54.54115488024847,
  ('fs', "Roy's greatest root"): 54.54115488024848,
  ('hp', "Wilks' lambda"): 214.4236072381088,
  ('hp', "Pillai's trace"): 214.4236072381091,
  ('hp', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 214.42360723810904,
  ('hp', "Roy's greatest root"): 214.42360723810907},
 'Pr > F': {('Intercept', "Wilks' lambda"): 0.0,
  ('Intercept', "Pillai's trace"): 0.0,
  ('Intercept', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 0.0,
  ('Intercept', "Roy's greatest root"): 0.0,
  ('pv', "Wilks' lambda"): 0.09116055879307752,
  ('pv', "Pillai's trace"): 0.09116055879307752,
  ('pv', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 0.09116055879303571,
  ('pv', "Roy's greatest root"): 0.09116055879307752,
  ('ed', "Wilks' lambda"): 6.284223443412654e-14,
  ('ed', "Pillai's trace"): 6.284223443412654e-14,
  ('ed', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 6.284223443411805e-14,
  ('ed', "Roy's greatest root"): 6.284223443412654e-14,
  ('fs', "Wilks' lambda"): 2.652650399331105e-24,
  ('fs', "Pillai's trace"): 2.652650399331105e-24,
  ('fs', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 2.6526503993306902e-24,
  ('fs', "Roy's greatest root"): 2.652650399331105e-24,
  ('hp', "Wilks' lambda"): 3.5971364993426025e-92,
  ('hp', "Pillai's trace"): 3.5971364993426025e-92,
  ('hp', 'Hotelling-Lawley trace'): 3.5971364993389216e-92,
  ('hp', "Roy's greatest root"): 3.5971364993426025e-92}})
```

I know that the multivariate omnibus test gives me some ideas about the associations between the predictors and the responses. What I want to do next is some linear hypothesis testing, but can't seem to figure that out in statsmodels. I can't seem to find any documentation with pointers.

For example, what I would like to do is to compare whether the effects of the predictors are the same across both responses. In R, using the car package `linearhypothesis()` function, I could do something like this:

```
rhs = matrix(c(1, -1), ncol=2)
linearHypothesis(model=mod, hypothesis.matrix="pv", rhs=rhs,
                 title = "equality of cofficients for pv predictor",
                 verbose=TRUE)

#where the rhs = matrix [1, -1] describes the coefficient difference I am testing for, while the 
#hypothesis.matrix='pv' restricts the coefficient difference I am testing to the pv predictor only.
```

Comment: docs are not very informative, examples when specifying L, M constraint matrices are in unit tests, starting around here https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/multivariate/tests/test_multivariate_ols.py#L78 later test case use contrast matrices instead of names

Comment: Thanks to @Josef I found the solution [here](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/multivariate/tests/test_multivariate_ols.py#L179)